# What is 'print' in Python?

Tags: python

I understand what `print` does, but of what "type" is that language element? I think it's a function, but why does this fail?

```
>>> print print
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Isn't `print` a function? Shouldn't it print something like this?

```
>>> print print
<function print at ...>
```

Comment: `print` may be a function or a statement (language construct), depending on the major version of Python you're using, but it's definitely not an operator.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In 2.7 and down, `print` is a statement. In python 3, `print` is a function. To use the print function in Python 2.6 or 2.7, you can do

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(print)
<built-in function print>
```

See [this section](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt) from the Python Language Reference, as well as [PEP 3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/) for why it changed.

Comment: Note that "Note" in the comment above is misspelled as "Not" ;)

Comment: About time they fixed that. The broken print statement is the #1 reason why haven't used Python in the past.

Comment: Not that the first comment formerly referred to a now-deleted comment.

Comment: @wim But I did not that the first comment could not refer to the one I do note see above it.

Answer (score 35):

In Python 3, [`print()`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#print) is a built-in function (object)

Before this, [`print`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) was a *statement*. Demonstration...

## Python 2.*x*:

```
% pydoc2.6 print

The ``print`` statement
***********************

   print_stmt ::= "print" ([expression ("," expression)* [","]]
                  | ">>" expression [("," expression)+ [","]])

``print`` evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting
object to standard output (see below).  If an object is not a string,
it is first converted to a string using the rules for string
conversions.  The (resulting or original) string is then written.  A
space is written before each object is (converted and) written, unless
the output system believes it is positioned at the beginning of a
line.  This is the case (1) when no characters have yet been written
to standard output, (2) when the last character written to standard
output is a whitespace character except ``' '``, or (3) when the last
write operation on standard output was not a ``print`` statement. (In
some cases it may be functional to write an empty string to standard
output for this reason.)

-----8<-----
```

## Python 3.*x*:

```
% pydoc3.1 print

Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
```

Comment: In Python 3 OP will get the same output, albeit for a different reason; `print print` is bad syntax in both.

Comment: @Wooble: Absolutely. Being a function, `print()` requires brackets. I inclued these in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I was just referring to "You must be using python < 3". The error message is literally identical to the OP's in both.

Comment: @Downvoter: I'm curious as to which parts of my answer you deemed "not useful".

Answer (score 21):

`print` is a mistake that has been rectified in Python 3. In Python 3 it is a function. In Python 1.x and 2.x it is not a function, it is a special form like `if` or `while`, but unlike those two it is not a control structure.

So, I guess the most accurate thing to call it is a statement.

Answer (score 7):

In Python all statements (except assignment) are expressed with reserved words, not addressible objects.  That is why you cannot simply `print print` and you get a `SyntaxError` for trying.  It's a reserved word, not an object.

Confusingly, you **can** have a variable named `print`.  You can't address it in the normal way, but you can `setattr(locals(), 'print', somevalue)` and then `print locals()['print']`.

Other reserved words that might be desirable as variable names but are nonetheless verboten:

```
class
import
return
raise
except
try
pass
lambda
```

Comment: "verboten" is used in english? funny.

Comment: @cularis: the word probably became more commonly used as a loanword because of American movies about World War 2.

Comment: Nothing confusing about that; in Python 2.6+  there is built-in `print` function all the time. `from __future__ import print_function` removes the `print-the-statement` parsing from the module, so that it doesn't interfere with the built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, which is a whole different kind of thing from a variable or function. Statements are not Python objects that can be passed to `type()`; they're just part of the language itself, even more so than built-in functions. For example, you could do `sum = 5` (even though you shouldn't), but you can't do `print = 5` or `if = 7` because `print` and `if` are statements.

In Python 3, the `print` statement was replaced with the `print()` function. So if you do `type(print)`, it'll return `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`.

**BONUS:**

In Python 2.6+, you can put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your script (as the first line of code), and the `print` statement will be replaced with the `print()` function.

```
>>> # Python 2
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> type(print)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```