# Why is assert a statement in Python?

Tags: python, assert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [design of python: why is assert a statement and not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390401/design-of-python-why-is-assert-a-statement-and-not-a-function)

In Python 3, print was made into a function.  What are the benefits of having assert be a statement?

Comment: well, it's not supposed to return anything, maybe that's why

Comment: `print` is not supposed to return anything either :)

Comment: @MikeCorcoran -- I was just about to point that out.  :)

Comment: Oops, sorry both.  Voted to close.

Answer (score 4):

For optimization.  If you run your Python script with the -O option no code will be generated for assert statements.  This would not be possible if assert were a function.

See the [documentation on assert](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement), which references this behavior.

Comment: +1.  I wonder whether pypy be able to optimize away empty functions one day…