# How to unpack Tuple containing bool and str for assert

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, assert, assertion

Is there a way to unpack a tuple containing boolean and custom message and apply assert on it in single line single statement?

```
def test_numbers(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return True,"Are Equal"
    return False, "Not equal"

res, st = test_numbers(1,2)
assert res,st
```

Then tried the following, which didn’t  work

```
assert *test_numbers(1,2)
```

same for:

```
assert (*test_numbers(1,2))
```

Comment: No, you can't unpack in a statement. What you have is as close as you can get.

Comment: [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13390401/12671057), especially the accepted answer.

Comment: I think you are trying to check all items of your tuple are truthy, you migh use `all` :
`assert all(test_numbers(1,2))`

Answer (score 3):

## Solved by Walrus operator for `python >= 3.8`

https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/
Finally, this issue can be settled.
The walrus operators `:=` purpose is exactly to avoid double computation.

```py
def check_numbers(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return True,"Are Equal"
    return False, "Not equal"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert (res:=check_numbers(1, 2))[0], res[1]
```

Comment: I'd rather add a function call that does `assert cond, msg` and call it like `validate(*check_numbers(1,2))`

Answer (score 1):

One can go the **detour over a custom assert function**, but there should be a nicer way.

At least this solution gives the generated error message and is not called, when optimization (-> `__debug__ == False`) is on.

```py
def check_numbers(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return True,"Are Equal"
    return False, "Not equal"

def custom_assert(cond, msg):
    # https: // docs.python.org / 3 / reference / simple_stmts.html  # the-assert-statement
    if __debug__:
        if not cond: raise AssertionError(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    custom_assert(*check_numbers(1, 2))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
assert test_numbers(1,2)[0]
```

Tuples can be indexed because they are iterables.

You don't need the 2nd value, do you ?