# What is the type of print in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

`sum` is a builtin function in Python, so that's why I get this output.

```
>>> type(sum)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

But when I do,

```
>>> type(print)
```

It returns

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    type(print)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, is there no type of print? Is `print` an exception to the `type()` function?

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: `print` is a statement not a function, you you can not use `type` for it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, which is a whole different kind of thing from a variable or function. Statements are not Python objects that can be passed to `type()`; they're just part of the language itself, even more so than built-in functions. For example, you could do `sum = 5` (even though you shouldn't), but you can't do `print = 5` or `if = 7` because `print` and `if` are statements.

In Python 3, the `print` statement was replaced with the `print()` function. So if you do `type(print)`, it'll return `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`.

**BONUS:**

In Python 2.6+, you can put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your script (as the first line of code), and the `print` statement will be replaced with the `print()` function.

```
>>> # Python 2
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> type(print)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Comment: Since this question has been closed as a duplicate, I hope it's alright to link to [this answer on the reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020417/what-is-print-in-python/31983419#31983419).

Answer (score 2):

`print` is not a function in Python 2, it is a statement.

Comment: Why isn't `type()` function capable of showing this information?

Comment: @Himanshu Because you cannot do `type(if)` or `type(pass)` either. Statements are not inspectable, they're keywords.

Comment: Because it's a statement! You can't show the type of `if` or `else` or `while`, either, because they're statements. It's like asking "what is the colour of yes".

Comment: @HimanshuMishra deceze beat me by a second, so I'll just add that `type(obj)` is equivalent to `obj.__class__`, and since `if`, `pass`, `print` etc are not objects in Python 2.7, they do not have a `.__class__`.

Comment: @yatisagade The analogy with `obj.__class__` explains it very well. Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) and `object.__class__`